# SQL query that selects values from different rows that has same id

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to select different values from different records that can have same or different ids based on values of a certain field. For Example:

```
ID, Color, Shape, Weight, Height, Price
1   blue   sq     10      12      5
1   red    sq     10      13      6
2   blue   sq     10      14      7
3   blue   sq     10      15      8
3   red    sq     10      16      9
```

And trying to get the following output:

```
ID, Color, Shape, Weight, Height, PriceBlue, PriceRed
1   red    sq     10      12      5          6
1   blue   sq     10      12      5          6
2   blue   sq     10      14      7          NULL
3   blue   sq     10      15      8          9
3   red    sq     10      15      8          9
```

So, when the color is red it needs to pick up height of blue but all the other field's would come from the red record. But it also needs to pick up the price of both records when the id is same.
When color is blue it needs to pick up all the blue field records plus price of both blue and red when both records have same id. 
If the record is unique (with no other record that has same id) then it has to pick up all the fields accordingly. The second price field would be null in that case.
I really appreciate any help. I tried to come up with a query but so far i cannot find a way to make the value of height that of blue record no matter what the color is.

Comment: You'll need to use a `FULL OUTER JOIN` to allow for rows with no match of the other color.

Comment: I understand. I could not complete my query because I just could not figure out how to select a value of different row when color is red. I could use the out join etc but somehow I need to figure out how to pick up height of blue when color is red. This is a bad example but that is the case I am trying to find solution for.

Comment: I need to gather all the information from all records however the tricky part is to always select value of blue for Height no matter what the color is for the given row.

Comment: Use a subquery that just returns the height of blue rows, and outer join with that on ID.

Comment: What if there's only a single red row for the id? What should be displayed in the height column - null or the red row's height?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this with analytic functions:

```
select ID, Color, Shape, Weight,
       max(case when color = 'blue' then height end) over
           (partition by id) as Height,
       max(case when color = 'blue' then Price end) over
           (partition by id) as Price_Blue,
       max(case when color = 'red' then Price end) over
           (partition by id) as Price_Red
from table t;
```

EDIT:

Those so inclined can test this code:

```
with t(ID, Color, Shape, Weight, Height, Price) as (
      select 1,   'blue',   'sq',     10,     12,      5 from dual union all
      select 1,   'red',    'sq',    10,      13,      6 from dual union all
      select 2,   'blue',   'sq',     10,     14,      7 from dual union all
      select 3,   'blue',   'sq',    10,      15,      8 from dual union all
      select 3,   'red',    'sq',     10,      16,      9 from dual
     )
select ID, Color, Shape, Weight,
       max(case when color = 'blue' then height end) over
           (partition by id) as Height,
       max(case when color = 'blue' then Price end) over
           (partition by id) as Price_Blue,
       max(case when color = 'red' then Price end) over
           (partition by id) as Price_Red
from t;
```

And [this](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8) is the SQL Fiddle.

[This](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/24239) is the SQL Fiddle for SQL Server.  And [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d41d8/4609) for Postgres.

Comment: This doesn't put the blue height in the red rows.

Comment: You're using an analytic function for `Price_Blue` and `Price_Red`. What analytic function are you using for `Height`?

Comment: Also, he only wants to use the "other" row to get the `Height` when `color = red`, not when `color = blue`.

Comment: You put the wrong sqlfiddle link, I just get a blank fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Two more possible solutions. In both cases, when there is only "red row" for id then I take height from this row.

Query 1:

```
with b as (select * from test where color='blue'),
  r as (select * from test where color='red')
select id, b.color, b.shape, b.weight, b.height, 
    b.price price_blue, r.price price_red
  from b left join r using (id)
union 
select id, r.color, r.shape, r.weight, 
    nvl2(b.color, b.height, r.height) height, b.price, r.price
  from r left join b using (id) order by id, color
```

---

Query 2:

```
select id, color, shape, weight,
    case 
      when color = 'red' then (
        case when exists (
            select 1 from test t1 where t1.id = test.id and color='blue')
          then (select height from test t1 where t1.id = test.id and color='blue') 
          else height end) 
      else height end height, 
    case when color = 'blue' then price else (select price from test t1 
      where t1.id = test.id and color='blue') end price_blue,
    case when color = 'red' then price else (select price from test t1 
      where t1.id = test.id and color='red') end price_red
  from test order by id, color
```